# get remote ip of address in a value for use in shell script

Tags: shell, get, centos, ip

I am using a CentOS server, and i want to get a remote dynamic ip in a value to use in a script.
Right now the script gets the ip like this:

```
    current_ip=$(curl --silent http://ipecho.net/plain)
```

but since i am moving the script to a server, i need it to ping my dyndns domain name and get my ip since its going to be changing every now and then.
Is there a way to do this with ping or something ?
So i can add in current_ip my ip every time the script executes ? 
-Thanks

Comment: Possible lead/"duplicate" on UNIX & Linux : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve a domain name, try the `host` utility:

```
$ host -t A stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 198.252.206.140
```

Comment: yup, i just figured it out also....searched for getip.sh in google...and someone had a similar script lol...using 
current_ip=$(host mydomain.sytes.net | grep address | cut -d " " -f 4)